# How to access dynamic element with selenium

Tags: java, angular, selenium-webdriver

I am doing functional testing on an angular application.

my current task is to fill out data on a page, submit the information, then verify that the results.

Once the submit button is clicked a new div is added to the page that could say any one of these things (ex: data saved, error in a certain field, error that the data being saved is already in the system etc.)

My issue currently is waiting for that div to appear before moving on to the next step because this is where my test is failing.

Depending on what message that div contains, a certain next step would be taken so waiting for some text to appear wouldn't work because that can vary.

I want to stay away from using implicit waits and strictly use explicit but everything I have tried so far doesn't work

I am facing this error:

```
org.openqa.selenium.NoSuchElementException: no such element: Unable to locate element:
```

I have tried:

- waiting for it to be visible
- waiting for it to be clickable (even    though I don't need to click
  but worth a shot)
- waiting for it to be present
- fluent wait

at this point Im out of ideas on how to wait until this element is present in order to access it.

I see that the element is added based on an *ng-reflect-if* but i'm not even sure if that makes a difference

**HTML Code**

```
<app-notification-box _ngcontent-c3="" _nghost-c4=""><!--bindings={
  "ng-reflect-ng-if": "true"
}--><div _ngcontent-c4="" class="row py-2 pl-2 pr-1 m-2 light-green-row" ng-reflect-klass="row py-2 pl-2 pr-1 m-2" ng-reflect-ng-class="[object Object]">  
  <div _ngcontent-c4="" class="col-1 m-0 py-0 pl-0 pr-2 tx-align-r max3p">
      <img _ngcontent-c4="" class="ic16" src="some source" hidden="">
      <img _ngcontent-c4="" class="ic16" src="some source">        
  </div>
  <!--bindings={
  "ng-reflect-ng-if": "true",
  "ng-reflect-ng-if-else": "[object Object]"
}--><div _ngcontent-c4="" class="col m-0 p-0 tx-align-l">
      successfully saved 
  </div>
  <!---->
</div>
<!--bindings={
  "ng-reflect-ng-if": "false"
}-->
<!--bindings={
  "ng-reflect-ng-if": "false"
}-->
<!--bindings={
  "ng-reflect-ng-for-of": "[object Object],[object Object"
}--><div _ngcontent-c4="">
  <!--bindings={
  "ng-reflect-ng-if": "false"
}-->
</div><div _ngcontent-c4="">
  <!--bindings={
  "ng-reflect-ng-if": "false"
}-->
</div>
</app-notification-box>
```

**Function Accessing element** with *xpath: "//*[@id=\"ui-main-content\"]app-notification-box[1]/div[1]/div[2]"*

WebElement is called *expectedResult*

```
public String checkExpectedResult(String expectedResultValue){
   //wait.until(ExpectedConditions.visibilityOf(expectedResult);
  //wait.until(ExpectedConditions.elementToBeClickable(expectedResult));
  //wait.until(ExpectedConditions.presenceOfElementLocated(expectedResult));

   Boolean actualResult = expectedResult.getText().equalsIgnoreCase(expectedResultValue); 
        if (actualResult) {
            clearButton.click();
            setAccount();
            checkNextExpectedResult();
            UtilityFunctions.generateScreenShot(driver, "Success");
            return "success";
        } else {
            String results = expectedResult.getText();
            UtilityFunctions.generateScreenShot(driver, expectedResult.getText());
            System.out.println("Actual Result: " + expectedResult.getText());
            refreshBrowser();
            return results;
        }

}
```

Comment: Could you post a code snippet and an HTML snippet?

Comment: Have you confirmed that the desired element is not inside an IFRAME?

Comment: @JeffC yes, it is not an iframe

Comment: Then we need to see the code you are using along with the relevant HTML that you are referencing or we're just guessing. Please add both to your question and format them properly.

Comment: @DavidBaak I've updated the question

Comment: @JeffC updated.